# How to retain table content and sorting with v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have a page with a search form and I use vuetify's data-table for the search results, which can be sorted by columns.

If I click on an item in the table, I'm forwarded to that item's edit page. Then, if I click on the back button (this.$route.go(-1)) all the search terms, search results and sorting is gone and I have to do the same search again.

So the question is, how do I retain all the results and sorting selection in the data table?

I guess I can use localStorage with the search form input values?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the localStorage indeed with :value or use and implement the Vuex to centralise your data source.

This would make your data persistent to navigation but not to hard refresh as local storage would.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using vuex module for storing search form input and url for storing column sorting data. So when I go back, I can fill the form from the vuex store and set sorting from the route query.